# How to find a block containing a transaction using transaction hash only?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block, bitcoinj, transaction-id

Well, the title says it all.
I have  a transaction hash and I want to find this transaction in the blockchain.
I am working with bitcoinj.

I am probably missing something very obvious here, but I cannot find how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction does not know the block in which it was integrated.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx

There are many services around like blockchain.info or blockexplorer.com which stores the blockchain and have indexed all transactions, which you can search.

Comment: Some transactions are in multiple blocks, for instance: https://blockchain.info/tx/392655224c035f4ace1dfb3d95f86406bfc82e646b27b731faeab052209e0b0a

Comment: The link only shows one transaction, and what you are suggesting is a double-spend. You cannot spend the same transaction outputs twice or more.

Comment: @T9b the link shows that it was included in the following blocks (one's an orphan, the other made it onto the main chain, both height 297359): https://blockchain.info/block-index/401024 https://blockchain.info/block-index/401025 So orphaned blocks are an exception to the rule, and probably not the point of the question.

Comment: Maybe not the point of the question, but i am showing that there is not always a unique answer. ... Another one, this time in 2 very early mainchain blocks (height 91722 and 91880):  https://blockchain.info/tx/e3bf3d07d4b0375638d5f1db5255fe07ba2c4cb067cd81b84ee974b6585fb468

Comment: @WillemHengeveld how is that possible?

Comment: looking at http://blockexplorer.com/b/91880  there is a remark about a bug in the miner that mined that block.

Comment: Does the p2p protocol support this?